# How to pass decimal value from textbox to parameter

Tags: c#, textbox, decimal, currency

I am trying to create a save `Button` and it includes 2 values in `TextBox` controls that are considered *currency* in *sql*.  They are `decimal` in the `TextBox`.  How do I pass the value?  I tried this to no avail:

```
decimal taxOpen = Convert.ToDecimal(taxOpenTextBox).Text;
```

Any help on the correct syntax would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to access the `Text` property. You also should use `TryParse`, which returns `false` instead of throwing an exception if the parse fails:

```
decimal value;

if(!decimal.TryParse(taxOpenTextBox.Text, 
                     NumberStyles.Currency, 
                     NumberFormatInfo.InvariantInfo, 
                     out value))
  MessageBox.Show("Please enter a valid number");
```

The needed things are found in `System.Globalization`.

Comment: I attempted the above but it keeps telling me its not a valid number.  What is in the box is $0.00 as that is the default value.  Does the $ cause the issue??

Answer (score 0):

You need to get the value of the taxOpenTextBox, not the box itself.

Comment: Oops that is my bad I tried that!  Either way it does not work.

Comment: @korrowan: the syntax as you have it in your edited question:   decimal taxOpen = Convert.ToDecimal(taxOpenTextBox).Text; would be looking for the Text property  of nothing-- you are still sending the text box itself to the ToDecimal method. The ".Text" must go *inside* the parentheses: ... (taxOpenTextBox.Text)